# iptables - правила - обьясните

Tags: unix, iptables

Обьясните как это работает и почему после внесения этих правил, замедляется ответ от сервера к примеру при заходе на сайт идёт как-бы задержка, если убрать, все более менее работает быстро.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j DROP
```

Comment: Эм, ну как бы эти правила и предназначены для ограничения скорости. Что именно неясно? Есть конкретные вопросы?

Comment: Для ограничения скорости чего именно ?  То есть как это работает - что именно ограничивает - нужен реальный пример

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим `man itables-extensions`:

> ### limit
>
> This module matches at a limited rate using a token bucket filter.  A rule using this extension will match until this limit is reached.  It can be used in combination with the LOG target to give limited logging, for example.
>
> xt_limit has no negation support - you will have to use `-m hashlimit !  --hashlimit` rate in this case whilst omitting --hashlimit-mode.
>
> - `--limit rate[/second|/minute|/hour|/day]` -- Maximum average matching rate: specified as a number, with an optional `/second`, `/minute`, `/hour`, or `/day` suffix; the default is 3/hour.
> - `--limit-burst number` -- Maximum initial number of packets to match: this number gets recharged by one every time the limit specified above is not reached, up to this number; the default is 5.

<sub><sup>Markdown скопирован из [этого ответа](https://serverfault.com/a/1006592).</sup></sub>

---

Более подробная документация [тут](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html) в limit match extensions.

Там же дан пример и указан график на превдографике на примере борьбы с DDOS акатами, собственно, вполне логичное применение. Если идёт непонятный интенсивный траффик, то он будет резаться по скорости, снизится нагрузка на сервер.

У вас лимиты стоят на `icmp` (Ping requests) и `tcp`. Всё что будет идти по `udp` резаться по скорости не будет.

Флаги `FIN`, `SYN` , `RST`, `ACK` подробно объяснены [здесь](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/tcp-flags):

| Флаг | Значение |
| --- | --- |
| FIN | Указывает на то, что соединение разрывается. И отправитель, и получатель посылают пакеты FIN для изящного завершения соединения. |
| SYN | Пакеты, которые используются для инициирования соединения. |
| RST | Сигнализируют о разрыве соединения или о том, что служба не принимает запросы. |
| ACK | Пакеты, которые используются для подтверждения того, что пакеты данных были получены, также используются для подтверждения запроса на инициирование и запроса на разрыв соединения. |

Comment: Приведу пример, есть сайт который проверяет сайт аптайм с разных стран, если приведённые выше правила фаервола не убрать, тогда при проверке сайт выдаёт максимум 5-6 позитивных ответов, если убрать, проверка происходит мгновенно, с успехом всех стран. Я так понимаю проблема именно в применении технологии проверки этого сайта, так как он возможно с одного айпи шлет сервер запросы просле 5-6 которых сервер - игнорирует остальные ?

Comment: @webstackoverload лимит вы поставили `1/sec`,  `--limit-burst` по дефолту 5, поэтому у вас рубит после 5. Если есть желание сохранить лимиты и не рубить после 5, можете попробовать указать число повыше. `--limit 1/sec --limit-burst 15 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Спасибо ! --limit-burst - действительно работает, увеличиваю значение и увеличивается пробивка аптайма - т.е больше успехов. Вопрос, а можно это как-то отслеживать, к примеру данное правило именно на сервере ? К примеру смотреть кто обращается и когда срабатывает к примеру обрыв (блок) итд ?

Comment: Просто я тут подумал если блочит проверку, то что будет если зайдет к примеру поисковый бот гугла и начнет делать запросы ?

Comment: @webstackoverload тоже самое и будет. Получит 5 ответов, если будет первым, а потом ничего не получит. Сейчас правило написано для всех подключений а не per ip. По поводу первого вопроса — можно, через логирование.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стали понятны многие моменты где я не мог понять почему так происходит ! Буду разбираться в настройках, так же изучу подробно как это технически работает. Спасибо еще раз !

Comment: @webstackoverload вы, вроде бы, не новенький, знаете, что не принято благодарить в комментах. Рекомендую ещё посмотреть в сторону [Shorewall](https://shorewall.org/ConnectionRate.html), программа над iptables, в которой гораздо проще разобраться, а разобравшись с ней проще ориентироваться в правилах iptables. Iptables довольно тяжёл в освоении.

Comment: Спасибо, я сразу удалил ufw.  Если изучать, так только - хардкор.